# Retrieve value from new column

Tags: mysql, opencart

I am trying to learn opencart structure, and trying to create a new column under the table `product`. The new column is "test"

Then I try to retrieve the data under this page `index.php?route=checkout/cart` (replace price with test column)

```
catalog\controller\checkout\cart.php
...

$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'key'      => $product['key'],
    'thumb'    => $image,
    'name'     => $product['name'],
    'model'    => $product['model'],
    'option'   => $option_data,
    'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
    'stock'    => $product['stock'] ? true : !(!$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout') || $this->config->get('config_stock_warning')),
    'reward'   => ($product['reward'] ? sprintf($this->language->get('text_points'), $product['reward']) : ''),
    'price'    => $product['test'],  //<-- new column
    'total'    => $total,
    'href'     => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']),
    'remove'   => $this->url->link('checkout/cart', 'remove=' . $product['key'])
);
```

The problem is I'm not getting any output, and I'm not sure how to work with the model. Which query/function is related with this page ?

Comment: The problem is that the `$products` that are available at `cart.php` controller are retrieved from the session where they have been stored in previously set structure, so there is no `test` index. See `/system/library/cart.php` and method `getProducts()` to understand what I am speaking about. If You would like to use this at `catalog/controller/product/category.php` or `catalog/controller/product/product.php` controllers, the code You are trying **will work**. If You replace the price within all product lists and product detail, the final price within cart would be Your `test` value.

Comment: @shadyyx yes it working under category.php and product.php, unfortunately not with controller\checkout\cart.php ...

Comment: @shadyyx thanks for your info after i see the code under /system/library/cart.php  now i understand how it work.. right now i can show my custom field under cart.php .. thanks again :)

Comment: I'll post the comment as an answer then so You can accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `$products` that are available at `cart.php` controller are retrieved from the session where they have been stored in previously set structure, so there is no `test` index and You should get a `Notice: undefined index 'test' in ...`. The `$products` are retrieved by

```
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
    //...
}
```

See `/system/library/cart.php` and method `getProducts()` to understand what I am speaking about.

If You would like to use this at `catalog/controller/product/category.php` or `catalog/controller/product/product.php` controllers, the code You are trying will work.

If You replace the price within all product lists and product detail, these controllers:

- product/

  - category.php
  - manufacturer_info.php
  - product.php
  - search.php
  - special.php
- module/

  - bestseller.php
  - featured.php
  - latest.php
  - special.php

with Your value, the final price within cart would be Your test value.